# Is there a way to simplify/hide STL backtrace in Visual Studio call stack view?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, stl

The call stack in Visual Studio 2015 becomes very difficult to read/deal with when using `std::bind`, `std::function`, STL algorithms, and other forms of functionality where eventually a function back in my own code base is reached. In between the "real" (my) calling code and the handling (again, my) code, there's usually 10-15 pieces of backtrace that are inside STL. Is there a way to hide or condense this information?